# Prove that sets are open in $(C[0,1],||.||_\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

How can I prove the the sets $A=\left\{ f \in C[0,1] : \left| \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx\right|<1 \right\}$ and $B=\left\{f \in C[0,1] : f ([0,1]) \subseteq (0,1) \right\}$ are open in $(C[0,1],||.||_\infty)$?

Comment: Pick any element in $A$ or $B$, show that if you perturb it by a small amount (with respect to $||\cdot||_{\infty}$, of course) it still remains in the given set. For $A$ it follows from $\mu([0,1])<\infty$ and for $B$ the fact that $[0,1]$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Easy by definition… the set A is open if for all $f \in A$ an $\varepsilon$ exists s.t. $g\in A$ for $||f-g||_\infty < \varepsilon$.

Consider that $$||f-g||_\infty < \varepsilon \iff \forall x: -\varepsilon < f(x) - g(x) < \varepsilon$$

So for A it follows $$\left| \int_{0}^{1} g(x) dx\right| \le \left| \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx\right| + \varepsilon$$

For B it follows: $$\max{g} \le \max{f} + \varepsilon$$ and $$\min{g} \ge \min{f} - \varepsilon$$

Just think about how to choose $\varepsilon$ and you're done…

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Phi: (C([0,1]), \|\cdot\|_{\infty}) \to (\Bbb R, |\cdot|)$ be defined by $\Phi(f) = \int_0^1 f(x)dx$. Verify that $\Phi$ is linear and bounded (so continuous). Let $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, $g(x) = |x|$, then also $g$ is continuous. Hence $\Psi : =g \circ \Phi$ is continuous. Now notice that $A = \Psi^{-1}((-\infty,1))$ is the inverse image by a continuous function of an open set, hence open.

Let $f\in B$, then $f([0,1]) \subset (0,1)$, but $f([0,1])$ is compact, so $f([0,1]) = [\epsilon, 1-\epsilon']$ for some $0 < \epsilon < 1 - \epsilon' < 1$. Let $\epsilon'' = \min \{\epsilon,\epsilon'\}$. Then $f([0,1]) \subset [\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$. This shows that the ball $B_{\|\cdot\|_{\infty}}(f,\epsilon/2)$ is contained in $B$.

Comment: Shouldn't be $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow$ [0,1)?

Comment: @RobertJames no. Why do you think so?

Comment: It is the absolute value in $\mathbb{R}$, isn' it?

Comment: @RobertJames yes.

Comment: Correction: I meant $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$.

Comment: @RobertJames: it does have $[0,\infty)$ as its range, but it doesn't matter what we put as the codomain as long as it contains $[0,\infty)$. If I were to put $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb C$, this would still be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the complement $B$ of $A$ an let $(f_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $B$ with limit $f$. Hence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$, therfore

$ \int_a^bf_ndx \to \int_a^bfdx$.

Since $ |\int_a^bf_ndx| \ge 1$ for all $n$,  it follows that $ |\int_a^bfdx| \ge 1$ . Thus $f \in B$ and $B$ is closed.